# Base class template member function shadowed in Derived class, albeit different parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

This has me wondering. Suppose I have :

```
class Base
{
public:

    template<typename T>
    void foo(T& varT)
    {
        //
    }

    template<typename T, typename U>
    void foo(T& varT, U& varU)
    {
        //
    }
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename U, typename Z>
    void foo(T& varT, U& varU, Z& varZ)
    {
        //
    }
};
```

Now when I try this:

```
Child c;

char cVar;
int iVar;
float fVar;

c.foo(cVar);
c.foo<int>(cVar);
c.template foo<int>(cVar);
```

None of the calls work. They are always shadowed with error 'No matching member function for call'. Can anybody point me to a way to resolve this? I read in the standard that derived objects shadow template functions inherited but the standard explicitly said that the parameter list must be the same if they are shadowed.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: *"but the standard explicitly said that the parameter list must be the same if they are shadowed"* Wrong. That's required for *overriding virtual functions*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hiding base members always happens when you have a name in a derived class that is present in a base class. The basic reason is that it is desirable to guard derived class uses against changes in the base class: assuming names from bases were not hidden, if a new overload in a base class is added a working look-up to a derived member may be hijacked to rather refer to the base class without any indication in the derived class that something may happen in the base class. If you mean to make the base members available, you can use a `using` declaration:

```
class Child : public Base
{
public:
     using Base::foo; // declare that you want look up members from the base class

     template<typename T, typename U, typename Z>
     void foo(T& varT, U& varU, Z& varZ)
     {
         //
     }
};
```

In your code you had three calls:

1. `c.foo(cVar)` works with the `using` declaration.
2. `c.foo<int>(cVar)` doesn't work even with the `using` declaration because you can't bind a non-`const` reference to `int` to a `char` lvalue. Using `c.foo<char>(cVar)` would work.
3. `c.template foo<int>(cVar)` suffers from the same problem. Since `c` is clearly not a dependent name, there is no need at all to use `template` in this context.

Without the `using` declaration you can call the member by qualifying the call explicitly, e.g.:

```
c.Base::foo(cVar);
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the clarification. Works like a charm. I will accept this a answer as soon as this lets me :)

Comment: @dyp: I rephrased the sentence (and added a bit of a rationale why names are hidden).

Comment: cool, found this while looking for whether template methods can override other template methods - looks like they can, and it does the sane thing!

Answer (score 0):

You need this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Add to Child's definition:

```
using Base::foo;
```